# How to get absolute path of a lua script file

Tags: lua

I have a lua script A.lua, which calls B.lua by specifying package.path. In B.lua, it has to use its absolute path. My question is, how can I get the absolute path of B.lua in B.lua? "PWD" doesn't work since PWD just return the current working directory. debug doesn't work either, since B.lua is not call from command line. Anyone have better solution?

Comment: In "B.lua" second vararg argument is the path: `local _, path = ...; print(path)`.  But the path is not absolute, and this doesn't work in Lua 5.1

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file somewhere in `package.path` that `require` is able to find, then you can also easily get the path by using [`package.searchpath`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath).

If `"foo.bar.baz"` is the name under which `require` will load the file, then

```
package.searchpath( "foo.bar.baz", package.path )
--> (e.g.) "/usr/share/lua/5.3/foo/bar/baz.lua"
```

gets you the path.

This works in Lua 5.2 or newer and LuaJIT as well.